# Meu HSD.test não funciona. Alguma dica de como fazer rodar?

Tags: r

Meu tratamento é em faixas e estou usando como base o script retirado do  livro "Experimentação Agrícola" Kronha & Banzatto pg 161, acessado pelo [site](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/doku.php/cursos:ragronomia).

Pretendo realizar a anova e em seguida o teste para definir as interações:

```
ex08.anovaRA<-anova(ex08.av$'bloco:camada')
ex08.anovaRA
```

## Testando fator camada

```
require(agricolae)
HSD.test(pH,camada,ex08.anovaRA$Df[2],ex08.anovaRA$Mean[2],alpha=0.05)
```

Após colocar isso no `RStudio`, ele roda, não aparece erros, porém não aparece a tabela de comparação. O que pode estar faltando no meu script?

Comment: Por favor, insira o seu banco de dados na pergunta com o comando: `dput(dados)`. O [link](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/doku.php/cursos:ragronomia) informado não funciona.

Comment: A pergunta está clara e é objetiva. Não entendo o motivo de ter sido fechada.

Answer (score 4):

Se você quiser que o output apareça no console precisa colocar o argumento `console = TRUE`.

Por exemplo:

```
> library(agricolae)
> data(sweetpotato)
> model<-aov(yield~virus, data=sweetpotato)
> HSD.test(model,"virus", group=TRUE)
> HSD.test(model,"virus", group=TRUE, console = TRUE)

Study: model ~ "virus"

HSD Test for yield 

Mean Square Error:  22.48917 

virus,  means

      yield      std r  Min  Max
cc 24.40000 3.609709 3 21.7 28.5
fc 12.86667 2.159475 3 10.6 14.9
ff 36.33333 7.333030 3 28.0 41.8
oo 36.90000 4.300000 3 32.1 40.4

Alpha: 0.05 ; DF Error: 8 
Critical Value of Studentized Range: 4.52881 

Minimun Significant Difference: 12.39967 

Treatments with the same letter are not significantly different.

      yield groups
oo 36.90000      a
ff 36.33333     ab
cc 24.40000     bc
fc 12.86667      c
```

No entanto, acho que o ideal é salvar o resultado em um objeto e ir dando `print` nas partes necessárias, por exemplo:

```
out <- HSD.test(model,"virus", group=TRUE)
out$means
out$statistics
out$parameters
```